# JBoss AS 7.1 not accepting remote connections

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x

I have done like this :[JBoss  AS 7 not accepting remote connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132657/jboss-as-7-not-accepting-remote-connections?answertab=votes#tab-top)

but it's still does't work?

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" interface="public" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Is there an error when it starts?

Comment: I have the same problem. There is not error and is working with this configuration only for localhost. The administration console is accessible through both : localhost and 192.168.x.x

Answer (score 3):

Try to change interfaces to point to the hostname of your system. And try to access it via your hostname or IP.

```
<interfaces>
  <interface name="management">  
    <!-- bind to the hostname -->  
     <inet-address value="your-hostname"/>
  </interface>
  <interface name="public">
    <!-- bind to the hostname -->
     <inet-address value="your-hostname"/>
  </interface>  
</interfaces>
```