# Accessing JBOSS-AS server for remote connections

Tags: jboss, centos, jboss7.x, war, remote-access

I recently installed JBoss AS 7 in CentOS 6.7 server. The jboss as works fine. For testing, I deployed a .war file and tested it, It works great!. But now I tried to access the same application from my desktop PC but it says ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE. I tried these below mentioned solutions but they didn't worked out for me, my bad.

[JBoss  AS 7 not accepting remote connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132657/jboss-as-7-not-accepting-remote-connections)
[Can't access JBoss AS 7 from remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210649/cant-access-jboss-as-7-from-remote-machine)

The server has a static IP with working DNS. I don't understand why I couln't access my application deplyoed remotely. Kindly feel free to ask me to provide further needed details.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I tried these, but didnt work
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21210649/cant-access-jboss-as-7-from-remote-machine
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132657/jboss-as-7-not-accepting-remote-connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IPTABLES firewall was blocking the ports. So I allowed the firewall to listen on port 9990 and 8080 and finally solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your standalone.xml to contain 0.0.0.0 in place of 127.0.0.1? search for all occurrences of 127.0.0.1 (localhost) and replace it with 0.0.0.0

For example -

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

This change, alongwith checking the "Listen on all interfaces to allow remote web connections" checkbox on your jboss server's Server Behavior section should work.

Comment: Yes. I solved it. The IPTABLES firewall was blocking the ports. So I allowed the firewall to listen on port 9990 and 8080 and finally solved it.